# Wordpress Multisite Language Switcher Plugin to display post url for different languages

Tags: wordpress, api, plugins, documentation, multilingual

I am currently using the Multisite Language Switcher Plugin on one of our webpages. I am trying to create a language switch button that will allow the user to go to the same post of the other language when they click on it.

So for example, if we have the english post and its equivalent in the welsh language, I would need to get the URL of its counterpart for the user to go to that page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Multisite Language Switcher Options first then add switcher button from elements to anywhere you'd like to display.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I know of this language switcher options. My question was, how could I get that value in PHP